# How to finds positions that are covarying in two or more aligned RNA sequences (in Perl)

Tags: perl, alignment, sequences

I'm very new to the perl language and have encounter a slight problem which I hope to get help with.

I want to be able to read a text file containing a set of aligned RNA sequences and print out each line as written in the text file. For example:

```
gccuucgggc
gacuucgguc
ggcuucggcc
```

And then I want to find the covarying position in all of these these following sequences. In the example above the second character both from the front and back is covarying in each sequence. I want to find the position where and which line is varying and print it out.

At the moment I'm able to print out each line in the text file as following:

```
open(RNAalign, $ARGV[0]) || "Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";

while ( <RNAalign> ) {
    $RNAseq .= $_;
}
print "$RNAseq\n";
@RNAseq=split('\n',$RNAseq);
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it but I'm hoping that I can get some help here after. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? [Text::Levenshtein](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/Levenshtein.pm) will be first step towards it I suppose.

Comment: @quinshi, Hi, can you provide example output of what you are looking for?

Comment: You should add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your program, predeclare variables using `my` and try and use the three-argument `open` with lexical filehandles. All of that will save you trouble in the long run. See http://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial for some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ( %hash, $stringNum, @covariances );

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $i = 0;
    $stringNum++;
    $hash{ $i++ }{ lc $_ } = 1 for split //;
}

for my $position ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash ) {
    push @covariances, $position if values %{ $hash{$position} } == $stringNum;
}

print Dumper \@covariances;
print "\n", Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
gccuucgggc
gacuucgguc
ggcuucggcc
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '8'
        ];

$VAR1 = {
          '6' => {
                   'g' => 1
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'u' => 1
                 },
          '7' => {
                   'g' => 1
                 },
          '9' => {
                   'c' => 1
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'c' => 1
                 },
          '8' => {
                   'c' => 1,
                   'u' => 1,
                   'g' => 1
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'c' => 1,
                   'a' => 1,
                   'g' => 1
                 },
          '4' => {
                   'u' => 1
                 },
          '0' => {
                   'g' => 1
                 },
          '5' => {
                   'c' => 1
                 }
        };
```

The script builds a hash of hashes, where the keys are the string positions `0 .. n`, and the associated values are references to hashes which track the character(s) in those positions.  If a characters differ across all strings in a given position, then the number of values associated with a key will be equal to the number of strings, indicating covariance. Note that `@covariances` contains `1, 8`.  The hash was dumped so you could see the data structure.

The script tracks the number of strings, and `split`s each string into its characters,k increment the key's value--held in `$i`--for each character.  The `for my $position ( ...` segment iterates through the keys, in numeric order, and `push`es the key (the string position) onto `@covariances` if there was a different character in each string (`values %{ $hash{$position} } == $stringNum`).

Hope this helps!